# Crossfilter - Loading a JSON file from localStorage

Tags: json, d3.js, graph, local-storage, crossfilter

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm trying to create a simple bar chart with d3.js using some data saved in the localStorage.

The data in the localStorage is acquired by the following function:

```
function logScore() {

var name = prompt("Please enter your name to add to the high scores list:");

var score = game.count;

var gameDate = today;

var scoreObj = { name: name, score: score, date: gameDate };

scoresArray.push(scoreObj);
window.localStorage.setItem('scoresRecord', JSON.stringify(scoresArray));
}
```

In a separate Javascript file, I parse the JSON object in order to store the object in an array.

```
var scoreData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('scoresRecord'));

queue()
.defer(d3.json, "scoreData")
.await(makeGraph);

function makeGraph(error, scoreData) {

var ndx = crossfilter(scoreData);

var name_dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('name'));
var score_dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('score'));
var date_dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('date'));

dc.barChart("#high-score-chart")
    .width(300)
    .height(150)
    .margins({ top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 })
    .dimension(date_dim)
    .group(score_dim)
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .xAxisLabel("Date")
    .yAxisLabel("Score");

dc.renderAll();
}
```

Once loaded, I then try to use the data in a d3.js barchart using crossfilter, but I get the below error from the console:

> https://ifd-project-simon-georgefairbairn.c9users.io/scoreData 404 (Not Found)

**I think I'm loading the data correctly, but I wondered if anyone would be able to let me know if I can use crossfilter and d3.js with a JSON object stored in localStorage, and if so how?**

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem - hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to get the data synchronously, loading it from local storage, then you don't need `queue()` and `d3.json`

You should be able to do

```
var scoreData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('scoresRecord'));
var ndx = crossfilter(scoreData);
```

The error you're getting indicates that `d3.json` is trying to do an HTTP request for the data. In this case, you don't need `d3.json` because JSON parsing is built into the language.

If you were using CSV data, then you might use the synchronous parse version `d3.csv.parse`. There is no `d3.json.parse` because it's provided directly by the language.